# Plugins loading multiple copies of JQuery

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I'm having issues where multiple copies of jQuery are being loaded onto the page via plugins that require jQuery.

I Just want to confirm that if I have 3 plugins active on my page, that all properly use **wp_enqueue_script** to load jQuery, will the library be included only once or 3 times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all three plugins load jQuery properly using `wp_enqueue_script("jquery")` then only one copy of jquery will be used.

If you are seeing three copies then some plugins are not playing nice.

Comment: I'd give an extra **+1** for the *not playing nice* comment. This is one of the biggest end-user annoyances in WordPress.

Comment: +1 what Chip said. I cannot say how often I have to deal with both plugins and themes that don't load jQuery "nicely". It's unfortunate that I actually get excited when I see a theme or plugin that is doing it correctly, instead of incorrectly.